# I ordered variegated ivy online - but got this

Tags: identification, shade

Last autumn, I wanted to have an attractive ground cover for a deep shade area. So I ordered five variegated English ivies, and planted them - or so I thought.

I noticed some flowers today. Looking now at them, they don't look like ivy's flowers at all. And I realized these are not hederas! Though it looks these plants like shade like hederas, and are evergreen too. I am really mad at the vendor - this is the third time I ordered something, and got a wrong plant, believe it or not!

Can you perhaps help me ID the plants, so that I at least know what I have?

Location is Serbia. Photos are here:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your region has temperatures that go below -18 C, then the plant is a cultivar of *Vinca minor*, possibly' Illumination' (if temperatures never get below -15 C or so, then it's possibly *Vinca major*). The plants are evergreen, and both species will spread along the ground, rooting at each node on a stem. A single plant can cover a large area in a short period of time. In some parts of the US V.minor is considered an undesirable invasive plant.

Comment: Yes, it is Vinca. I looked at https://gardenerdy.com/vinca-major-vs-vinca-minor-whats-difference/, and, judging by leaf and flower sizes, it is Vinca minor, no doubt.

Comment: As for cultivar, it looks neither 'Alba Variegata' https://www.google.com/search?q=%E2%80%98alba+variegata%E2%80%99+vinca&tbm=isch (green leaves with yellow/white edges, but white flowers) nor 'Illumination' https://www.google.com/search?q=%E2%80%98illumination%E2%80%99+vinca&tbm=isch (yellow leaves with green edges).

Comment: Could it be that the cultivar is just 'Variegata' https://www.google.com/search?q=%E2%80%98variegata%E2%80%99+vinca&tbm=isch ?

Comment: @AlexAlex - It certainly could be Variegata. Illumination may be a cultivar only available in North America. And because V. minor is native to the Caucasus and surrounding areas, this plant could also be a locally created hybrid.